# how to locate element in webdriver for embedded flash

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to locate a button on this embedded window using firebug but due to flash-embedded objects, I am not able to do it.

How I can locate elements in embedded objects in Web driver? Code is as below:

```
<embed id="ExploriaCMS" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" wmode="window" 
allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" name="Exploria" bgcolor="#5D5B5E"
quality="high" flashvars="moduleName=presentations" src="../GUI/ExploriaCMS.swf">
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do Flash Testing directly, you would need a Third party add on that serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use external interfaces in the flash object and call these using the JavascriptExecutor of the WebDriver. I've been able to read controls (buttons, textfields, etc) and click buttons on the Flash using this method.